# get any item from map without loop

Tags: go

```
package main

import ()

type Scope struct {
    Type   int // 1,2,3
    Parent *Scope
}

func main() {

    scopes := map[*Scope]string{}
    filter(scopes)
}

// key is always the same type of scopes
func filter(scopes map[*Scope]string) {
    // This function only works for scopes of Type 1,3
    // if the Type is 2 return
    // I just need to pick any item in the map to do a check

    for k := range scopes {
        if k.Type == 2 {
            return
        } else {
            break
        }
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I have to check the type of the key of a map.
The keys of the map are of the same type.
so I just need to pick any item from the map.

```
for k := range scopes {
        if k.Type == 2 {
            return
        } else {
            break
        }
        // Do something
    }
```

this code does the check but is there a way doing this without evolving loop?

Comment: No there is no other way to get a key, you can omit the else however and just break after the if block.

Comment: This code also doesn't do anything. If the first element's `k.Type  == 2`, the function immediately returns. Otherwise, it breaks from the `for`... and the function immediately returns. The entire function body could be removed and the behavior would be the same.

Comment: @Adrian added // Do something